# Scala: def method[A](some params) vs def method(some params)

Tags: scala

I'm having trouble finding what this is called and what the difference is exactly between defining a method like this:

`def method[A](//...//) {}`

or

`def method(//...//) {}`

Also, is `def method[A]` the same as `def method[Any]`?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`def method[A]` defines a *generic type* `A`.  Used like this, with no refinement, it is a wildcard that can be satisfied by any type.  (You can specify that only some subtypes are allowed with syntax like `[A <: Foo]`, where `Foo` is a class or trait you've defined.)

Why would you want to do this?  Most likely, you want a method that returns the same type that it takes as an argument (or some variation thereof--maybe it takes a list of that type and returns an array of that type):

```
def method[A](a: A): A = ...
```

Since you don't know anything about `A`, it is as generic as `Any`.

Now, there's nothing special about `A`.  You could put anything there, even `Any`:

```
def method[Any](a: Any) ...    // Don't do this!
```

But this would be supremely confusing, because this isn't your standard `Any` type that is at the top of the inheritance hierarchy--it's a generic type just like `A`, but with a longer name.

If you don't need to use a generic type, omit the `[A]`.  For example:

```
def printed[A](a: A): A = { println(a); a }   // Generic necessary
def printMe(a: Any) { println(a) }            // Not necessary, returns Unit
```

Comment: That makes sense although I would then assume that I would have issues when I try things like: `def method[Int](a: List[String]): String = { "foo" }` but this works in the REPL...  Thoughts?  (and thanks)  Do I not get issues because I'm not using generics?  I tried your `printed` function without the [A] and I got barked at...

Comment: @MCP - Try using `Int` within that method!  You'll find that it is not the `Int` you mean, but a generic type.  (So, no `+` or anything.)  Note that the comment says **generic necessary** on the first one, so yes, you would get barked at!